# How to call a variable value from one template to another template using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, dita, dita-ot

Hi I need to call a variable value from one template to another template in an xsl file of dita ot plugin:

My Ditamap file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE pubmap
  PUBLIC "urn:pubid:com.sam.doctypes:dita:pubmap" "pubmap.dtd">
<pubmap xml:lang="en-US">
  <pubtitle>
    <mainpubtitle outputclass="book">Sample Word</mainpubtitle>
  </pubtitle>
  <topicref href="topics/topic_1.dita">
    <topicmeta>
      <navtitle>Ram-Files-Raj (RFR)</navtitle>
      <metadata/>
    </topicmeta>
  </topicref>
  <topicref href="topics/topic_2.dita">
    <topicmeta>
      <navtitle>Files-Sampletitle (FST)</navtitle>
      <metadata/>
    </topicmeta>
  </topicref>
</pubmap>
```

My topic_1.dita file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic
  PUBLIC "urn:pubid:com.sam.doctypes:dita:topic" "topic.dtd">
<topic id="topic_1" xml:lang="en-US" outputclass="Ram-Files-RajRFR"><title>Ram-Files-Raj (RFR)</title></topic>
```

My topic_2.dita file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic
  PUBLIC "urn:pubid:com.sam.doctypes:dita:topic" "topic.dtd">
<topic id="topic_2" xml:lang="en-US" outputclass="Files-SampletitleFST"><title>Files-Sampletitle (FST)</title></topic>
```

My XSLT template having the needed variable "output-class":

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="set-output-class">
  <xsl:param name="default"/>
  <xsl:variable name="output-class">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="get-output-class"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="draft-revs">
    <!-- If draft is on, add revisions to default class. Simplifies processing in DITA-OT 1.6 and earlier
         that created an extra div or span around revised content, just to hold @class with revs. -->
    <xsl:if test="$DRAFT = 'yes'">
      <xsl:for-each select="*[contains(@class, ' ditaot-d/ditaval-startprop ')]/revprop">
        <xsl:value-of select="@val"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="using-output-class">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string-length(normalize-space($output-class)) > 0"><xsl:value-of select="$output-class"/></xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="string-length(normalize-space($default)) > 0"><xsl:value-of select="$default"/></xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:if test="$draft-revs != ''">
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($draft-revs)"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="ancestry">
    <xsl:if test="$PRESERVE-DITA-CLASS = 'yes'">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="get-element-ancestry"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="outputclass-attribute">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@outputclass" mode="get-value-for-class"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <!-- Revised design with DITA-OT 1.5: include class ancestry if requested; 
       combine user output class with element default, giving priority to the user value. -->
  <xsl:if test="string-length(normalize-space(concat($outputclass-attribute, $using-output-class, $ancestry))) > 0">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
      <xsl:value-of select="$ancestry"/>
      <xsl:if test="string-length(normalize-space($ancestry)) > 0 and 
                    string-length(normalize-space($using-output-class)) > 0"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($using-output-class)"/>
      <xsl:if test="string-length(normalize-space(concat($ancestry, $using-output-class))) > 0 and
                    string-length(normalize-space($outputclass-attribute)) > 0"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="$outputclass-attribute"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

from this above template i need to fetch the "output-class" variable to below template:

```
<xsl:template match="/*[df:class(., 'map/map')]">
    <xsl:param name="doDebug" as="xs:boolean" tunnel="yes" select="false()"/>

    <xsl:variable name="effectiveCoverGraphicUri" as="xs:string">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="get-cover-graphic-uri"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- FIXME: Add mode to get effective front cover topic URI so we
         can generate <guide> entry for the cover page. Also provides
         extension point for synthesizing the cover if it's not
         explicit in the map.
    -->

    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="report-parameters">
      <xsl:with-param name="effectiveCoverGraphicUri" select="$effectiveCoverGraphicUri" as="xs:string" tunnel="yes"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>

    <xsl:variable name="graphicMap" as="element()">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="generate-graphic-map">
        <xsl:with-param name="effectiveCoverGraphicUri" select="$effectiveCoverGraphicUri" as="xs:string" tunnel="yes"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="uplevels" select="$uplevels" as="xs:string" tunnel="yes" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:message> + [INFO] Collecting data for index generation, enumeration, etc....</xsl:message>

    <xsl:variable name="collected-data" as="element()">
      <xsl:call-template name="mapdriven:collect-data"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:if test="$doDebug">
      <xsl:message> + [DEBUG] Writing file <xsl:sequence select="relpath:newFile($outdir, 'collected-data.xml')"/>...</xsl:message>
      <xsl:result-document href="{relpath:newFile($outdir, 'collected-data.xml')}"
        format="indented-xml"
        >
        <xsl:sequence select="$collected-data"/>
      </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:result-document href="{relpath:newFile($outdir, 'graphicMap.xml')}" format="graphic-map"
      >
      <xsl:sequence select="$graphicMap"/>
    </xsl:result-document>
    <xsl:call-template name="make-meta-inf"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="make-mimetype"/>

    <xsl:message> + [INFO] Gathering index terms...</xsl:message>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="generate-content">
      <xsl:with-param name="collected-data" as="element()" select="$collected-data" tunnel="yes"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:if test="$epubtrans:isEpub3">
      <xsl:if test="$doDebug">
        <xsl:message> + [DEBUG] generating EPUB3 nav</xsl:message>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="epubtrans:generate-nav">
        <xsl:with-param name="collected-data" as="element()" select="$collected-data" tunnel="yes"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:if test="$doDebug">
        <xsl:message> + [DEBUG] after generate-nav</xsl:message>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
    <!-- NOTE: The generate-toc mode is for the EPUB2 toc.ncx, not the HTML toc -->
    <xsl:if test="$epubtrans:isEpub2 or $epubtrans:isDualEpub">
      <xsl:if test="$doDebug">
        <xsl:message> + [DEBUG] generating EPUB2 toc.ncx...</xsl:message>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="generate-toc">
        <xsl:with-param name="collected-data" as="element()" select="$collected-data" tunnel="yes"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:if test="$doDebug">
        <xsl:message> + [DEBUG] after generate-toc</xsl:message>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="generate-index">
      <xsl:with-param name="collected-data" as="element()" select="$collected-data" tunnel="yes"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:if test="$doDebug">
      <xsl:message> + [DEBUG] after generate-index</xsl:message>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="generate-book-lists">
      <xsl:with-param name="collected-data" as="element()" select="$collected-data" tunnel="yes"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:if test="$doDebug">
      <xsl:message> + [DEBUG] after generate-book-lists</xsl:message>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="generate-opf">
      <xsl:with-param name="graphicMap" as="element()" tunnel="yes" select="$graphicMap"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="collected-data" as="element()" select="$collected-data" tunnel="yes"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="effectiveCoverGraphicUri" select="$effectiveCoverGraphicUri" as="xs:string" tunnel="yes"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:if test="$doDebug">
      <xsl:message> + [DEBUG] after generate-opf</xsl:message>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$doDebug">
      <xsl:message> + [DEBUG] Generating graphic copy Ant script...</xsl:message>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="generate-graphic-copy-ant-script">
      <xsl:with-param name="graphicMap" as="element()" tunnel="yes" select="$graphicMap"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:if test="$doDebug">
      <xsl:message> + [DEBUG] after generate-graphic-copy-ant-script</xsl:message>
    </xsl:if>
<xsl:variable name="sample" 
      select="relpath:newFile($outdir, 'sample.xhtml')" 
      as="xs:string"/>
<xsl:result-document href="{$sample}" format="html5">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
          <title>sample</title>
          <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        </head>
        <body>
          <section id="minitoc">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="exists($outputclass = 'Ram-Files-RajRFR')">
      <h1><xsl:value-of select="//topic[@outputclass='Ram-Files-RajRFR']"/></h1><hr/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="exists($outputclass = 'Files-SampletitleFST')">
      <h2><xsl:value-of select="//topic[@outputclass='Ram-Files-RajRFR']"/></h2><hr/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>

    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose></li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </body>      </html>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:template>
```

Please suggest output-class variable fetching in '/*[df:class(., 'map/map')]' template.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<xsl:template match="*" mode="set-output-class">` template returns `attribute()?`. So if you want to get this result as is, following code in your `<xsl:template match="/*[df:class(., 'map/map')]">` template will work:

```
<xsl:variable name="classAttr" as="attribute()?">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="set-output-class"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Or if you want get the string value:

```
<xsl:variable name="classValue" as="xs:string" select="string($classAttr)"/>
```

will be sufficient.

> i need topic file output classes attribute value for review

I'm not sure for EPUB transform. But following code may be one of the solution.

```
    <xsl:variable name="topicOutputClasses" as="attribute()*">
        <xsl:for-each select="*[contains(@class,' map/topicref ')][exists(@href)]">
            <xsl:variable name="topicRef" as="element()" select="."/>
            <xsl:variable name="href" as="xs:string" select="$topicRef/@href/string(.)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="topicDoc" as="document-node()" select="document($href,$topicRef)"/>
            <xsl:sequence select="$topicDoc/*[contains(@class,' topic/topic ')]/@outputclass"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
```

> how to compare the particular outputclass from the all the output classes

Changing previous variable as xs:string* will make it possible to use in your xsl:when/@test as expected.

```
<xsl:variable name="outputclasse" as="xs:string*">
    <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*[contains(@class,' map/topicref ')][exists(@href)]">
        <xsl:variable name="topicRef" as="element()" select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="href" as="xs:string" select="$topicRef/@href/string(.)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="topicDoc" as="document-node()" select="document($href,$topicRef)"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="$topicDoc/*[contains(@class,' topic/topic ')]/@outputclass/string(.)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

You can use this variable with general comparison operator "=" such like this:

```
<xsl:when test="$outputclass = 'Ram-Files-RajRFR'">
```

> its not fetching the value inside h1 using this `<h1><xsl:value-of select="//topic[@outputclass='Ram-Files-RajRFR']"/></h1>`

If you succeeded to get the @outputclass value from topic files, following code will be also work.

[Variables in your map template]

```
<xsl:variable name="outputclasses" as="xs:string*">
    <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*[contains(@class,' map/topicref ')][exists(@href)]">
        <xsl:variable name="topicRef" as="element()" select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="href" as="xs:string" select="$topicRef/@href/string(.)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="topicDoc" as="document-node()" select="document($href,$topicRef)"/>
        <xsl:if test="exists($topicDoc/*[contains(@class,' topic/topic ')]/@outputclass)">
            <xsl:sequence select="$topicDoc/*[contains(@class,' topic/topic ')]/@outputclass/string(.)"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="topicHrefs" as="xs:string*">
    <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*[contains(@class,' map/topicref ')][exists(@href)]">
        <xsl:variable name="topicRef" as="element()" select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="href" as="xs:string" select="$topicRef/@href/string(.)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="topicDoc" as="document-node()" select="document($href,$topicRef)"/>
        <xsl:if test="exists($topicDoc/*[contains(@class,' topic/topic ')]/@outputclass)">
            <xsl:sequence select="$href"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

[Get the topic content]

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$outputclasses = 'Ram-Files-RajRFR'">
                <xsl:variable name="index" as="xs:integer" select="index-of($outputclasses,'Ram-Files-RajRFR')"/>
                <xsl:variable name="href" as="xs:string" select="$topicHrefs[$index]"/>
                <xsl:variable name="topicDoc" as="document-node()" select="document($href,.)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$topicDoc/*[contains(@class,' topic/topic ')]"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This code is redundant. You can customize it as you like.

Comment: Hi @tmakita, by using your code i am getting attribute of output classes of map file only but i need topic file output classes attribute value for review i have added my topic and map file code to the question can you please suggest me.

Comment: @User515 I'm not sure what middle file structure you are using. If you are using merged middle file (such like PDF2), it is possible to get topic element from topicref of map. Could you clarify your transformation details?

Comment: I need to fetch the " outputclass="Ram-Files-RajRFR"", outputclass="Files-SampletitleFST" the topic outputclass values from the topic files inside the '/*[df:class(., 'map/map')]' template. please assist. thanks

Comment: Thank you @tmakita its fetching the outputclasses but can you please suggest me how to compare the particular outputclass from the all the output classes as edited in the last part of the question when statement.

Comment: Thank you @tmakita but its not fetching the value inside h1 using this <h1><xsl:value-of select="//topic[@outputclass='Ram-Files-RajRFR']"/></h1>

Comment: Thank you so much @tmakita for giving answers with patience, its working fine.